# /sbin/sysctl was overwritten accidentally , How do we restore it CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, sysctl

We accidentally overwrote file /sbin/sysctl with command echo 1 > /sbin/sysctl

How do we restore the file in centos?

Comment: From your backups of course.., or use `rpm -qf /sbin/sysctl` to determine which rpm package to reinstall?

Comment: Hi, I am absolute newbie. But here is what I have understood from your commend. ( Please confirm if the understanding is correct )

Step 1: executed rpm -qf /sbin/sysctl
O/P: procps-ng-3.3.10-10.el7.x86_64

Step 2: I should run below command
yum reinstall procps-ng-3.3.10-10.el7.x86_64

Right? Does it have any impact on already running server applications like apache / mysql etc? or any other impact on live production system.

Comment: Installing procps is probably safe, but if you're worried wait for a maintenance window.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on HBruijn's comment, here's a sequence of commands that should get that file (and anything else from the same package) back.
Note that you need to use `yum reinstall` as `yum install` will just tell you that the package is already up-to-date.

```
[root@centos7-01 msmtp]# rpm -q -f /sbin/sysctl
procps-ng-3.3.10-10.el7.x86_64

[root@centos7-01 msmtp]# yum reinstall procps-ng
...
Installed:
  procps-ng.x86_64 0:3.3.10-10.el7

Complete!
```

Comment: Thanks Paul
Its truly a great help.

But as I am an absolute newbie would like to understand if these commands would have any impact on live applications such as apache and mysql running on the same machine, Its a production machine :S

Comment: Getting below error

`[root@vij ~]# yum reinstall procps-3.2.8-30.el6.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Reinstall Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/mirrors-rpmforge error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'"
 * base: mirror.fibergrid.in
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: mirror.fibergrid.in
 * updates: mirror.fibergrid.in
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'
`

Comment: Ah, now that's a different problem, @Rahul. Fix your DNS resolution. :)

Answer (score 1):

- Reinstall the RPM.
- Copy it from another system.
- Restore the file from your backups.

Comment: Getting below error [root@vij ~]# yum reinstall procps-3.2.8-30.el6.x86_64 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Setting up Reinstall Process Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/mirrors-rpmforge error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'" * base: mirror.fibergrid.in * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id * extras: mirror.fibergrid.in * updates: mirror.fibergrid.in http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/repodata/repo‌​md.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'